# Meteor finding this._id in onRendered function

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have an initializing function and I want to detect when a label is removed for a dropdown menu (from Semantic UI):

**call.js**

```
Template.calledit.onRendered(function() {
   $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
      onLabelRemove(value) {
         console.log(value);
         console.log(this._id);
      }
   });
});
```

**call.html**

```
<template name="calledit">
   <div class="field">
     <label>Assign Units</label>
     <div id="edit_call_assign_units_{{_id}}" class="ui multiple search selection dropdown">
       <input type="hidden" name="edit_call_assign_units_{{_id}}" value="{{units}}">
       <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
       <div class="default text">Assign Units</div>
       <div class="menu">
         <div class="item" data-value="420">420</div>
         <div class="item" data-value="F-117">F-117</div>
         <div class="item" data-value="805">805</div>
         <div class="item" data-value="230">230</div>
         <div class="item" data-value="506">506</div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
<template>
```

However, I have a problem with detecting the `_id` of the template that it was called in.  How would I access `this._id` in the onRendered function?

Comment: Can you please add the template code that goes with this? 'this' is not pointing to your Doc so this._id may not be defined.  Add console.log(this) to inspect the object that is being passed to onLabelRemove.

Comment: @SaeedD. I have console logged it but I cannot find the _id.  I also have added the template to the main topic.  I'm kind of stumped on how to do this :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like wrong context, maybe this

```
Template.calledit.onRendered(function() {
   var tmpl = this;
   $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
      onLabelRemove(value) {
         console.log(value);
         console.log(tmpl._id);
      }
   });
});
```

Or if you use ecmascript, then

```
Template.calledit.onRendered(function() {
   $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
      onLabelRemove: (value) => {
         console.log(value);
         console.log(this._id);
      }
   });
});
```